# Ошибка с возвращаемым значением в producer-consumer

Tags: java, многопоточность, синхронизация

В данном коде пытаюсь реализовать паттерн producer-consumer. Проблема возникает там, где её не ждал - при запуске этого кода возникает ошибка в методе `get()`:

> This method must return a result of type int

Подозреваю, это связано с тем, что `return` спрятан в цикле и не факт, что он будет вызван? Как тогда поправить этот код, чтобы два потока попеременно подавали и возвращали значение `n`?

```
public class ProdCons2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Q q = new Q();
            new Producer(q);
            new Consumer(q);
        }
    }
    
    class Q{
        int n;
        boolean valueSet = false;
        
        synchronized int get(){
            while(!valueSet){
                try{
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e){}
                System.out.println("Получено: " + n);
                valueSet = false;
                notify();
                return n;
            }
        }
        
        synchronized void put(int n){
            while (valueSet){
                try{
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e){}
                this.n = n;
                System.out.println("Отправлено: " + n);
                valueSet = true;
                notify();
            }
            
            }
    }
    
    class Producer implements Runnable{
        Q q;
        static int i = 0;
        
        Producer(Q q){
            this.q = q;
            new Thread(this, "Поставщик").start();
        }
        
        public void run(){
            
            while(i<200){
                q.put(i++);
                }
        }
    }
    
    class Consumer implements Runnable{
        Q q;
        
        Consumer(Q q){
            this.q=q;
            new Thread(this, "Потребитель").start();
            }
        
        public void run(){
            {
                while(Producer.i<200){
                q.get();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Функция должна возвращать значение в любом случае, а не в цикле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно вынести код за пределы цикла

```
    class Q{
        int n;
        boolean valueSet = false;
        
        synchronized int get(){
            while(!valueSet){
                try{
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
            System.out.println("Получено: " + n);
            valueSet = false;
            notify();               
            return n;
        }
        
        synchronized void put(int n){
            while (valueSet){
                try{
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
            this.n = n;
            System.out.println("Отправлено: " + n);
            valueSet = true;
            notify();                               
        }
    }
```